# Is there a way to log outbound HTTP requests that pass through my Airport Extreme?

Tags: wifi, airport, logs, http

My wireless router is an Airport Extreme.  I would like to log all outbound HTTP requests (leaving my Mac for an internet web server) for later review.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to install [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/)  HTTP Proxy through [Brew Package manager](http://brew.sh/)

Squid is a HTTP Proxy and will log and cache all **Browser** requests passing through it.Since we are installing Squid on your Mac, it will log only the one's passing through it.

Procedure :

1. Install Brew using Terminal.app
2. Make sure Brew is ready to be used by used by running following command:
  $
  **brew doctor**
  If not ready follow the instructions.

  (Generally this requires you to upgrade XCode to latest version.
3. Install Squid
  **$ brew update && brew install squid**
4. Point your Browser  to use Proxy localhost:3128

Comment: So, @Garfield Carneiro, if a 2nd Mac in my house uses my Airport, would the proxy record its HTTP requests?  I suppose it would if I pointed it at the proxy?  And if I did that, the 2nd Mac would only be able access the internet if the first Mac was on?

Comment: Yes. The computer which has Squid  installed has to be switched on as well as [configured](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch32_:_Controlling_Web_Access_with_Squid)  to accept requests from other computer as well.

Comment: If you are not comfortable configuring Squid, you could perhaps use a GUI programs like [SquidMan](http://squidman.net/squidman/) , [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) [etc](https://www.google.com/search?q=http%20proxy%20for%20mac), though I have never used any GUI configuration tools myself.